# How do I add a custom link with empty navigation label to menu in WordPress?

Tags: css, wordpress, qtranslate

I added a custom link to menu in WordPress, as shown below.

[image]

How do I remove the text `Language:`? In other word, how do I add a custom link with empty navigation label? I try to use empty string `""`, but it does work.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the soluation. Change the `URL` to,

```
#qtransLangSw?title=none
```

Refer to [Can I change the look of Language Switcher Menu?](https://qtranslatexteam.wordpress.com/faq/#LanguageSwitcherMenuConfig).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a custom plugin or template. The part where it says "Language:" is most likely uneditable without creating a child template or modifying the source code. Can you give me a list of the plugins you are using ?

Comment: It is modifiable. Any non-empty string works, such as `EN`. `Lauguage:` is the default text.

Comment: The related plugin is [qTranslate X](https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate-x/).

Comment: Thx a lot. I find a solution, just change the URL to `#qtransLangSw?title=none`.

Answer (score 0):

what if you leave it blank without quotes

Comment: When I click `Save Menu`, the link doesn't even appear in the menu.

Comment: if you inspect the menu with chrme inspector or ff you will find it just the css must be modified by specfying line-height attribute, because the label is blank the the height is 0

Comment: Thx a lot. I find a solution, just change the URL to `#qtransLangSw?title=none`.