# How to add a Wordpress Menu-Item with blank navigation label?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, menu, navigation

I try to set up a menu-item without a navigation label.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AikSNhBAk4teuBM_OsgNHEini7AC

If I save it, it disappears.

Is there a way to add a menu-item which got a blank navigation label?
I found another thread, but it was not helpfull in my case.

[How do I add a custom link with empty navigation label to menu in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39649682/how-do-i-add-a-custom-link-with-empty-navigation-label-to-menu-in-wordpress)

Does anybody know, how I can make the label not be displayed?

Comment: Can you please share your url?

Comment: Our Page is not online yet, we don't want to be ranked or seen until we are out :)
I am just searching for a general code snippet which is inside a label and says "I can stay empty" :)

Like on the thread mentioned above "#qtransLangSw?title=none" but without gtrans. https://1drv.ms/u/s!AikSNhBAk4teuBefTTIu0pYKEYkN

Thank you for your understanding :)

Comment: You got the solution l) cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I found the solution: Just use "&n.bsp;" inside the navigation label without the "." and it will work.